# how to solve problem running code for MySQL8 on MySQL 5.7?

Tags: window-functions, mysql-5.7

I have the following data:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
| xType   | xAccID | xAccName | xCat | xYear | xMonth | xRaseed   |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 11     | 3144.83   |
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 12     | -15199.64 |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 12     | 5306.04   |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 11     | 1090.64   |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

actually, I want to sum the (xRaseed) in the current row with the (xRaseed) in the previous row For each (xAccID) separately

the result that I want:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
| xType   | xAccID | xAccName | xCat | xYear | xMonth | xRaseed                        |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 11     | 3144.83                        | 
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 12     | Not -15199.64 But (-12,054.81) |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 12     | 5306.04                        |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 11     | Not 1090.64 But (6,396.68)     |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

I applied the following solution that I got from somebody here:

```
select t.*,
       sum(xRaseed) over (partition by xAccID order by xYear, xMonth) as running_xRaseed
from t;
```

but everything was working in the local server but when I applied the solution on my hosting, didn't work?? in the local I use (xampp - 10.4.17-MariaDB), and in my hosting, I use (MySQL 5.7.23-23), what's the problem, please?

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c425e64d5ad6f6a4c252fa4bb1e5816a)  is a db<>fiddle

Comment: Either use user-defined variable and emulate ROW_NUMBER (2 table copies needed) or use 3 table copies (2 joined + 3rd in NOT EXISTS) for to find adjacent row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On versions of MySQL earlier than 8+, we can use a correlated subquery to find the rolling sum:

```sql
SELECT xType, xAccID, xAccName, xCat, xYear, xMonth,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.xRaseed) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.xAccID = t1.xAccID AND
           (t2.xYear < t1.xYear OR
            t2.xYear = t1.xYear AND t2.xMonth <= t1.xMonth)) AS xRaseed
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    xAccId,
    xYear,
    xMonth;
```